# How can I view the list of files previously deleted by Storage Sense?

Tags: windows-10, storage, cleaning, storage-sense

How can I view the list of files previously deleted by Storage Sense? I use Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can.  However, it should only be looking at directories, that do not actually store data that is required (i.e. Temporary Files). Even the legacy Disk Cleanup tool did not generate a report of which files it deleted when it was ran. A report of what has already been deleted cannot be generated, but what can be done in the future, is to use a different tool that does generate a report of which files are deleted when it's ran.  Storage Sense and Disk Cleanup do not generate a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) [mentionned](https://superuser.com/questions/1767665/how-can-i-view-the-list-of-files-previously-deleted-by-storage-sense#comment2751459_1767665) in the comment section, one cannot view the list of files previously deleted by Storage Sense.

[J-M](https://serverfault.com/users/321227/j-m) mentioned in
[What exactly does Storage Sense consider Temporary Files?](https://serverfault.com/q/1076551) a few folders that Storage Sense may delete files from:

> - Downloads (unchecked, I believe this is controlled separately via ConfigStorageSenseDownloadsCleanupThreshold)
> - Windows Update Cleanup
> - Windows upgrade log files
> - Thumbnails (unchecked)
> - Microsoft Defender Antivirus (unchecked)
> - Delivery Optimization Files (unchecked)
> - Temporary files (I guess this is user's *Temp* folder)
> - Temporary Internet files
> - Windows error reports and feedback diagnostics
> - DirectX Shader Cache